# Interprocess communication between 32- and 64-bit apps on Windows x64

Tags: c++, winapi, interprocess

We'd like to support some hardware that has recently been discontinued. The driver for the hardware is a plain 32-bit C DLL. We don't have the source code, and (for legal reasons) are not interested in decompiling or reverse engineering the driver.

The hardware sends tons of data quickly, so the communication protocol needs to be pretty efficient.

Our software is a native 64-bit C++ app, but we'd like to access the hardware via a 32-bit process. What is an efficient, elegant way for 32-bit and 64-bit applications to communicate with each other (that, ideally, doesn't involve inventing a new protocol)?

The solution should be in C/C++.

Update: several respondents asked for clarification whether this was a user-mode or kernel-mode driver. Fortunately, it's a user-mode driver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is a real driver (kernel mode), you're SOL.  Vista x64 doesn't allow installing unsigned drivers.  It this is just a user-mode DLL, you can get a fix by using any of the standard IPC mechanisms.  Pipes, sockets, out-of-proc COM, roughly in that order.  It all operates on bus speeds so as long as you can buffer enough data, the context switch overhead shouldn't hurt too much.

Answer (score 3):

I would just use sockets.  It would allow you to use it over IP if you need it in the future, and you won't be tied down to one messaging API.  If in the future you wish to implement this on another OS or language, you can.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://dnjonline.com/article.aspx?ID=jun07_access3264) might be of interest.  It discusses the problem and then suggests using COM as a solution.  I'm not a big fan of COM but given its ubiquity in the Windows universe, it's possible that it might be efficient enough.  You will probably want to architect your solution so that you can batch data (you don't want to do one COM call for each item of data).

Answer (score 1):

Elegant? C++? DCOM/RPC calls to yourself might work, or you could create a named pipe and use that to talk between the two processes (maybe create a "CMessage class" or something), though watch out for different structure alignment between x86 and x64.

Answer (score 1):

If the driver does turn out to be a real driver, nobugz is almost right -- you're going to have to work a lot harder, you're not completely SOL.  One solution is to install Win32 on some other machine (or virtual machine) and then use some form of RPC, such as sockets (as suggested by Pyrolistical) or UDP or MQ or even Tibco Rendezvous (which claims to support very high throughput in order to handle the volumes of data generated by the financial markets -- at least that's what I remember from back in the old days).

Answer (score 1):

A memory-mapped file, shared by both sides would have the same contents. The OS will have to do some interesting pointer stuff to make it happen, but quite likely will be able to setup the 2 views in such a way that you're not physically copying memory around. Zero copies is about as good as it gets